# Unable to delete a folder recursively in Azure Data Lake

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I wish to delete a folder in Azure Data Lake. The folder contains sub-folders and files. This is what I have tried:

```
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint("https://aiops3e1fb6dcf0fef5.dfs.core.windows.net")
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();
delete(dataLakeServiceClient);
DataLakeFileSystemClient core = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("core");

String toDelete = "2022/01/25/09/30/";
System.out.println(core.getFileClient(toDelete).exists()); // prints true

DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = core.getDirectoryClient(toDelete);
directoryClient.deleteWithResponse(true, null, null, Context.NONE);
```

It gave me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> com.azure.storage.file.datalake.models.DataLakeStorageException:
> Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"InvalidUri","message":"The request
> URI is
> invalid.\nRequestId:9dcb8894-d01f-0026-5b93-19b89e000000\nTime:2022-02-04T06:53:17.1733402Z"}}"
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at
> com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:389)
> at
> com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$7(RestProxy.java:444)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:125)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCacheTime.java:293)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:192)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
> at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime.subscribeOrReturn(MonoCacheTime.java:143)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:57)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:119)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:184)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:128)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
> at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
> at
> reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702)
> at
> reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
> at
> io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1371)     at
> io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1245)
> at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1285)     at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446)
> at
> io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
> at
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
> at
> io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    Suppressed:
> java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error      at
> reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
> at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707)        at
> com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.blockWithOptionalTimeout(StorageImplUtils.java:128)
> at
> com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeDirectoryClient.deleteWithResponse(DataLakeDirectoryClient.java:142)
> at azure.DataLakePrac.delete(DataLakePrac.java:49)      at
> azure.DataLakePrac.main(DataLakePrac.java:25)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the trailing `/` fixed the issue:

```
String toDelete = "2022/01/25/09/30";
```

Now it was able to delete the folder (recursively)

**Note:** It also failed if the path was `/2022/01/25/09/30` (forward slash at start).